# django rest framework throttling per user and per view

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, throttling

i have two api view (django rest framework):

```
class ApiView1(APIView):
    ...
    throttle_classes = (UserRateThrottle, )
```

and api 2:

```
class ApiView2(APIView):
    ...
    throttle_classes = (UserRateThrottle, )
```

and my settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...,
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'user': '5/minute'
    }
}
```

when request the ApiView1 for five time, every thing is okay, but after that when request the ApiView2, i get a http 429 status code with:

```
Request was throttled. Expected available in 45 seconds.
```

**Question**: can i use throttling per user and per view? if yes, How it can be done?

Answer (score 3):

Because it's the feature of [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#scopedratethrottle).

> The ScopedRateThrottle class can be used to restrict access to specific parts of the API. This throttle will only be applied if the view that is being accessed includes a .throttle_scope property. The unique throttle key will then be formed by concatenating the "scope" of the request with the unique user id or IP address.
>
> The allowed request rate is determined by the DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES setting using a key from the request "scope".

Since you don't set the throttle_scope the any view, both `ApiView1` and `ApiView2` use the same throttle scope `scope`. So they share the same limit. If one view is over-accessed, another view will be unacceptable either.

In your scenario, you should set different throttle_scope in the apiview and add the scope to `REST_FRAMEWORK.DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES`.

If you have many throttle scope and don't want to add too many scopes in `settings.py`, you should create your own `Throttle` class and override the `get_cache_key` function.

```
class MyThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    def get_cache_key(self, request, view):
        return "throttle_{viewid}_{indent}".format(
            viewid=id(view),
            indent=self.get_indent(request)
        )
```

This ThrottleClass can automatic set different scope for different view.

Comment: If I want to have a default throttle rate for every api view (rate separately), then aside from adding all scopes (100 views then 100 scopes) to the settings, is there any other solution?

Comment: I updated the answer, you can use the `MyThrottle` class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

For class-based views:

```
class YourView(APIView):
    throttle_classes = (UserRateThrottle, )

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = { ... Your response here ... }
        return Response(content)
```

For function-based views you can use the decorator: `@throttle_classes([UserRateThrottle])`

_Reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/

Comment: thank you for your reply, I did the same thing, but when using `UserRateThrottle` for two APIView, throttling sum up all requests count for two views, in other word, i want throttle per view